# Passing HTML input form contents for calculation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a graph of a simple function `y=k*x+b`.
A user enters a function into the input field, for example:

> 1/3*x+3

and when he/she clicks the submit button, a JavaScript function is supposed to take this input value as an actual calculation sequence and assign a variable to it (I only need to get certain y values here, so the x variable has its limits):

```
for (x=1;x<=40;x++)
{
    result = window.document.menu.inputFunction.value;
}
```

The above code doesn't work. No wonder why - I am just a beginner at this. However, is this really harder than it looks, or am I missing out something? I considered trying regular expressions for this at one point, but my head hurts by even thinking about using them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it:

```
result = eval(window.document.menu.inputFunction.value);
```

There are obviously some limitations to this approach:

- The user must enter a valid javascript expression
- The user must use `x` as variable name because that's what you are using in the loop
- The code is vulnerable because the user can enter and execute any javascript expression he likes

For a more robust solution you might consider using a javascript [mathematical expression evaluator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsexpressioneval.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This graph would only be used offline, so I don't think security is in question. In addition, there are no SQL databases here, so the risk of SQL injection is gone too. And yes, I'm going to add pop-up boxes (tooltips) to inform the user about the syntax. Should I filter and validate the form?
What could possibly go wrong? I mean, what code could the user execute? Is it anything that could damage the server, should the graph be uploaded to one?

Comment: Thank you for the link, but for educational purposes I'd like to practise the development of this javascript code myself.